# Min SDK version for android application

Tags: android, version, android-manifest

I have following permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Min sdk version is set to 8. Maybe it can be less than 8?

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it can definitely be less than 8.**

It actually depends on the APIs and Classes that you are using in your code. If they are supported at lower SDK level, then you can set the minSDK to be lower.

But, I should suggest you to **not make it less than 7**, i.e. *Android 2.1*.

Comment: How can I check is correct min_sdk_version set or not? For example I set minSdkVersion 1 and eclipse doesn't give any error.

Comment: If you set a lower SDK level, and then go to your xml files (containing the layout, etc), it would say whether the widget is supported by the SDK or not. If it is too low, it would show an error in the layout file, not in the manifest file.

Comment: I am not sure how the Java code reacts to the minSDK level, it would crash if the SDK is too low. Start with 7 and increase it only when you are trying to use some API which requires higher.

Comment: As @swayam said: It actually depends on the APIs and Classes that you are using in your code, so MAYBE your code is valid for that version. In spite of that, I agree with his suggestion of not making it less than 7.